# How do I add a fraction to a EditText of type number?

Tags: android-studio

I'm making a Matriz Resolution app but i need to add fraction number in EditText. My problem is Android Number Keyboard doesn't have fraction number to add

Thanks for the time to explain to me

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an `inputType` for your `EditText`:

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />
```

Or do it in a Java file:

```
EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```